# fast way to create a transition frequency table

Tags: r, optimization

I have a table showing sequences of patterns, represented with the id of the sequence, and the ordered value of the consecutive patterns over several rows. patterns have all the same length but sequences have different lengths)

```
patterns_seq_a <- c("ABC", "BCD", "ABC", "CBA")
patterns_seq_b <- c("BCD", "BCC", "BAC", "ABC", "BCD")
patterns_seq_c <- c("ABC", "ABC")
sequence_df <- data.frame(sequence_id = c(rep("a", length(patterns_seq_a)),
                         rep("b", length(patterns_seq_b)),
                         rep("c", length(patterns_seq_c))),
                  pattern = c(patterns_seq_a, patterns_seq_b, patterns_seq_c))
```

and I'm trying to count the frequency from one pattern to another over all the sequences.
(and ultimately will build a probability of transitions from the frequency table)
so for example looking at the transition from "CBA" to "BCD" its frequency over all sequences would be 0 (NB the row 4 and 5 don't belong to the same sequence).
The end result would have the form of:

```
unique_patterns <- unique(sequence_df$pattern)
result <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = length(unique_patterns), nrow = length(unique_patterns)))
colnames(result) <- unique_patterns
rownames(result) <- unique_patterns
```

(but could also be a hash pattern -> pattern -> frequency if it has to)

On the web I've found a solution based on concatenations of sequences then greps but I it's unusable as it's too slow (profvis blames the greps). Something on the lines of this:

```
freq_table <- c()

for (start_pattern in unique_patterns) {
  for (end_pattern in unique_patterns) {
    transition_pattern <- paste0(start_pattern, ',', end_pattern)
    sequence_holding_transition <- concat_sequence_df[grep(transition_pattern, concat_sequence_df$patterns_sequence),]
    if (nrow(sequence_holding_transition) < 1) {
      transition_frequency <- c(transition_pattern, 0)
    } else {
      concat_sequence_holding_transition <-  paste0(sequence_holding_transition$patterns_sequence, collapse = ",", sep="/")
      transition_pattern_positions <- gregexpr(pattern = transition_pattern, text = concat_sequence_holding_transition)[[1]]
      transition_frequency <- c(transition_pattern, length(transition_pattern_positions))
    }
    freq_table <- rbind(freq_table, transition_frequency)
  }
}


frequency_table <- data.frame(pattern_transition = freq_table[, 1], counts = freq_table[, 2])
frequency_table$pattern.from <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(frequency_table$pattern_transition), ","), `[`, 1)
frequency_table$pattern.to <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(frequency_table$pattern_transition), ","), `[`, 2)

frequency_table <- t(matrix(as.numeric(as.character(frequency_table$counts)), ncol=length(unique_patterns), nrow=length(unique_patterns)))
colnames(frequency_table) <- unique_patterns
rownames(frequency_table) <- unique_patterns
```

I haven't been able to vectorize it and those greps are really slow in any case. I tried parallelizing it but it's still too slow.
Would someone have a lightning fast solution of building this frequency table?
I don't really care about the code sample, it's just here to show an example of a - unusable- solution.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

please find bellow the expected output if I know how to count.
To have lines with no transitions (such as "CBA" to "XXX") dropped is acceptable, and ofc it doesn't matter the actual type of the structure:

```
structure(
  list(
    ABC = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
    BAC = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
    BCC = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
    BCD = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    CBA = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
  ),
  row.names = c("ABC", "BAC", "BCC", "BCD", "CBA"),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want: is it along these lines 1. get a transition table for each id 2. combine then i.e. `sequence_df$pattern = factor(sequence_df$pattern); 
with(sequence_df, 
     Reduce("+",
     lapply( split(sequence_df, sequence_id) , function(i)
       table(i$pattern[-nrow(i)], i$pattern[-1]))))`

Comment: if thats correct maybe data.table will be faster; `dt = as.data.table(sequence_df);
dt[, pattern := factor(pattern)];
dt[, pl := shift(pattern), by=sequence_id][ ,pl := factor(pl, level=levels(pattern))];
with(dt, table(pl, pattern))`

Comment: @user20650 Can you please turn that comment into an answer? The code will be more readable, I will be able to upvote and Will will be able to accept the answer.

Comment: @Bernhard; I had been waiting for a response from op to see if it was what was expected. I also notice that it is very similar to your answer, so please feel free to incorporate any of my comments if you think they are useful

Comment: @user20650 My answer does not even produce the expected matrix, yours does.

Comment: Hello, sorry if I'm slow, I'm just starting with R... I posted my answer to both you and Bernhard's solutions bellow so that the code is more readable. As I see it both tapply and dt solve the problem, but dt is faster, though Bernhard seems to imply my post-processing is inefficient...

Comment: I have now added the expected output, which should clarify things (provided no miscount of my part)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I had a look at the solutions from @Berhard and @user20650 and while I haven't seriously validated the results yet, it looks that they both do the job.
one difference is that the `tapply` doesn't generate the 0 frequency transitions while `data.table` does.
Both solutions are faster than the nested for / rbind example as expected.
So I have tried to benchmark both, and assuming no mistake on my side adapting your code, the data.table is more than twice faster than the tapply one.
Thank you both for these elegant answers, appreciated!

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
library(microbenchmark)


patterns_sequences <- lapply(seq(1:8), function(id) {
                          length_sequence <- sample(3:10, 1);
                          do.call(paste0, replicate(3, sample(c("A", "B", "C"), length_sequence, TRUE), FALSE))
                          })

sequence_df <- data.frame(sequence_id = c(rep("a", length(patterns_sequences[[1]])),
                                          rep("b", length(patterns_sequences[[2]])),
                                          rep("c", length(patterns_sequences[[3]])),
                                          rep("d", length(patterns_sequences[[4]])),
                                          rep("e", length(patterns_sequences[[5]])),
                                          rep("f", length(patterns_sequences[[6]])),
                                          rep("g", length(patterns_sequences[[7]])),
                                          rep("h", length(patterns_sequences[[8]]))),
                          pattern = unlist(patterns_sequences))

build_frequency_table_base <- function(sequence_df) {

  ft0 <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(tapply(sequence_df$pattern, sequence_df$sequence_id,  FUN  =
                                             function(p) paste0(p[-length(p)], ",", p[-1])))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  ft1 <- ft0 %>%
    tidyr::separate(Var1, c("from_pattern", "to_pattern"), ",")

  ft5 <- tidyr::spread(ft1, to_pattern, Freq, fill= 0)
  rownames(ft5) <- ft5$from_pattern
  ft5$from_pattern <- NULL
  ft5
}

build_frequency_table_dt <- function(sequence_df) {
  dt = as.data.table(sequence_df);
  dt[, pattern := factor(pattern)];
  dt[, pl := shift(pattern), by=sequence_id][ ,pl := factor(pl, level=levels(pattern))];
  res_dt <- with(dt, table(pl, pattern))
  res_dt <- as.data.frame.matrix(res_dt)

}

tictoc::tic("base")
res_base <- build_frequency_table_base(sequence_df)
tictoc::toc()


tictoc::tic("DT")
res_dt <- build_frequency_table_dt(sequence_df)
tictoc::toc()

(bench = microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  build_frequency_table_base(sequence_df),
  res_dt <- build_frequency_table_dt(sequence_df),
  times=1000L
))
ggplot2::autoplot(bench)
```

[image]

Comment: I am not quite shure, whether one should call it a base version when so much of the time is spent in rearranging the result with tidyverse stuff and with an unnecessary pipe etc. That being said, `data.table` versions have a habbit of regularly being the fastest solutions. Before reading the benchmarking code of seeing the result I would have expected a `data.table` version to be the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

I have not benchmarked it but it seems, that the following solutions uses basic R functions that tend to usually be fast. Given `sequence_df` from the question:

```
table(unlist(tapply(sequence_df$pattern, sequence_df$sequence_id,  FUN  = 
                    function(p) paste0(p[-length(p)], p[-1]))))
```

I am using `tapply` to examine each `sequence_id` on it's own and `paste0` for the transition patterns. `unlist` puts it all in one large vector which `table` can count. I am not shure, whether one would call that fully vectorized but at least it has no nested `for` loops and no regular expressions.

It certainly lacks code to transform the table type into a matrix right now. That can be written once we know how it compares runtime wise with other solutions and depending on whether the matrix is really the ideal format for the operations to come after that.

Comment: Hello Bernhard, while I understand the concept, i dont really understand *how* p[-length(p)], p[-1] works. ok you are going to create the transitions from 1 pattern to the following one, but what is p? why the -length(p) and the -1 ?

Comment: I called `tapply` with an anonymous function starting with `= function(p) ...`. That is where `p` originates. It is a vector of patterns that `tapply` calls the function with. Hope, that is understandable.

Comment: ok, what i was missing is -x means drop element at position x if I understand correctly. thanks for taking the time!